# Insert data in MYSQL table error

Tags: mysql

I have big problem. I have 2 related tables: Parent and Child which are related by primary and foireign key.

primary table:

```
CREATE TABLE `project_main` (
  `ProjectMainId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectTitle` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectShortTitle` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectIntroduction` text

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

child table:

```
CREATE TABLE `project_detail` (
  `ProjectDetailId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ProjectProtocolNumber` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectNumberPatients` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ProjectNumberSites` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
  `ProjectMainId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When I try to insert data into Parent table, MySQL Says:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
>   fails (ctb_db.project_main, CONSTRAINT project_main_ibfk_1
>   FOREIGN KEY (ProjectMainId) REFERENCES project_detail
>   (ProjectMainId))

This thing does not happened in **MSSQL** database :(

regards,
Vasko

Comment: That table creation code you posted does not define any foreign keys. Please add that definition to your question. We harldy can offer help without a clear definition.

Comment: ALTER TABLE `project_main`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `project_main_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ProjectMainId`) REFERENCES `project_detail` (`ProjectMainId`),

Comment: Please do not add additional information in comments. Add them to the question itself. There is  an `edit` link below your question. _Use it_.

Comment: Ok, so you have an external key constraint. Which apparently gets violated by your insert attempt. So the question is: how does your insert statement look like?

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to insert data using PHPMyAdmin and SQLYog. I am not using code to insert. It is doing for me :)

Comment: Pls do not add your part of question as answer. Attache this part with question

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert a value in the child key column named ProjectMainId that dont exists in the Project_main table. The php my admin auto created a relationship.

Answer (score 0):

No, I am just insert data into Project_main table. Project_detail is empty. I am inserting data into Project_main and afther that when autoincrement generates ProjectMainId, I am inserting into ProjectDetail. But relation does not give me to insert data into project_main table. That is a problem.

Comment: Pls do not add your part of question as answer. Attache this part with question

Answer (score 0):

Do not define foreign key relationship for primary table. Define on child table. Here you defined  FOREIGN KEY  Constraint to primary table. Set this constraint to child table. You have done opposite way here.

Comment: @Vaso Zonjic: According to your explanation this is the correct answer. Pls can you mark this as correct (if you can).

Answer (score 0):

I figured what is a problem. I have created relation in SQLYog and it inverted relations :( Now I am fixing all relations in PHPMYADMIN designer. Never use SQLYog, please.